# Execute a timer Function Early

Tags: go, timer

When using `time.AfterFunc`, is it possible to execute the timer function early, cancelling the future execution of the function?

EDIT: The best way I can think of is to keep a function pointer parallel to the timer that points to the same function that is registered with the timer. You can then call this function and call timer.Stop(). My question remains though: Is there a way **inherent** to the timer that allows for this?

Comment: AfterFunc does not allow an immediate start. It may be possible to stop the timer, reset and set the value to be 0. May be worth trying. As it stands now though, you could probably get a less complex solution by just using a regular timer and doing what you'd like manually.

Comment: @John see Peter's answer below. This is essentially a RunImmediate function.

Comment: Nice! That's a really clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply stop the timer and reset it to zero, causing it to fire immediately:

```
t := time.AfterFunc(d, f)

// later

if t.Stop() {
   t.Reset(0)
}
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/yKBa0Mp_mUm

Note that it is necessary to check the return value of stop, else the function may be invoked multiple times:

> For a timer created with AfterFunc(d, f), if t.Stop returns false, then the timer has already expired and the function f has been started in its own goroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Per the documentation on `AfterFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#AfterFunc) (emphasis mine):

> AfterFunc waits for the duration to elapse and then calls f in its own goroutine. **It returns a Timer that can be used to cancel the call using its Stop method.**

As to how to actually execute the function early, once the timer is stopped, there's no reason to think about it. You have a function you want to execute now, so execute it now, just like any other function.

```
t := time.AfterFunc(dur, fn)
if t.Stop() {
   go fn()
}
```

Comment: That is not what I asked.

Comment: How can I **execute** early

Comment: @fishrec by calling the function. You have to have a function to pass to `AfterFunc`, which means you can call that same function whenever you want it to be executed.

Comment: Yes, which means it need stored somewhere which complicates the logic. The point is to avoid this. See Peter's answer below for a solution that involves virtually no other code.

Comment: also if you are going to edit your answer, please note that you are doing so.

Comment: If you look just below the answer, you'll see it's noted automatically when was edited. There's no reason to add a redundant comment saying the same thing.